# Heroku Application Crashes Because of Database

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, flask

My code works locally, but when I try running it on Heroku it does not work.I have added a db on heroku, but it still won't work. Any clues to why this happens?

```
import sys
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db_local =   #it works, just not shown here

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', db_local)

app.secret_key = '  '  #it's a secret for a reason

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from views import *
from model import *
db.create_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Some of my heroku logs

```
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "app.py", line 23, in <module>
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     from views import *
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/views.py", line 1, in <module>
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import db
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 25, in <module>
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     db.create_all()
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 822, in create_all
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy.py", line 814, in _execute_for_all_tables
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 2564, in create_all
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     import utils
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/utils.py", line 1, in <module>
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     conn = self.contextual_connect(close_with_result=False)
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2490, in contextual_connect
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.pool.connect(), 
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     tables=tables)
2013-02-19T22:29:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     con = self._create_connection()
```

Comment: What is the output of <code>heroku env</code>?

Comment: heroku env ouputs `env` is not a heroku command. <code>heroku env</code> outputs syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: What I meant was `heroku config`. (sorry)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I imagine the value of `DATABASE_URL` in your config vars does not exist. You can verify this via `heroku config:get DATABASE_URL --app your-app`

Try `heroku pg:info --app your-app` to find out what databases you have installed. Make sure your database is also DATABASE_URL (it would also show up in the output of `pg:info`). If it's not, just run `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_<color> --app your-app` and try your script again.

Comment: Thank you so so much. I had to promote it for it work. Do you know why I needed to promote it. I am just curious, since shouldn't it work from the get go.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputation to give you a vote up, but I gave you a checkmark (hint: vote up the question so that I can vote up this answer faster :P )

Comment: you need to promote it so that DATABASE_URL points to something that your app can pick up and use. It wasn't promoted for you automatically for unknown reasons to me, but the symptoms were enough to point you at the right direction. At heroku, on first push, we provision a database and promote it if we detect that you need one (eg: a rails app with the pg gem in its Gemfile). But if you created the database via heroku addons:add, you need to promote it yourself.

Comment: Oh ok. I was not given one initially for some reason, so yeah I had used the addon command. Thanks for the clarification