# Connecting psycopg2 with Python in Heroku

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, heroku, psycopg2

I've been trying for some days to connect my python 3 script to PostgresSQL database(`psycopg2`) in Heroku, without Django.

I found some article and related questions, but I had to invest a lot of time to get something that I thought should be very straightforward, even for a newbie like me.

I eventually made it work somehow but hopefully posting the question (and answer) will help other people to achieve it faster.

Of course, if anybody has a better way, please share it.

---

As I said, I had a python script that I wanted to make it run from the cloud using Heroku. No Django involved (just a script/scraper).

Articles that I found helpful at the beginning, even if they were not enough:

- [Running Python Background Jobs with Heroku](https://bigishdata.com/2016/12/15/running-python-background-jobs-with-heroku/)
- [Simple twitter-bot with Python, Tweepy and Heroku](http://briancaffey.github.io/2016/04/05/twitter-bot-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 10):

Main steps:

**1. Procfile**

`Procfile` has to be:

```
worker: python3 folder/subfolder/myscript.py
```

**2. Heroku add-on**

Add-on `Heroku Postgres :: Database` has to be added to the appropriate personal app in the heroku account.

To make sure this was properly set, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14971054/5802289) was quite helpful.

**3. Python script with db connection**

Finally, to create the connection in my python script `myscript.py`, I took [this article](https://community.c9.io/t/connecting-to-postgres-database-on-heroku/9991) as a reference and adapted it to Python 3:

```
import psycopg2
import urllib.parse as urlparse
import os

url = urlparse.urlparse(os.environ['DATABASE_URL'])
dbname = url.path[1:]
user = url.username
password = url.password
host = url.hostname
port = url.port

con = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=dbname,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            host=host,
            port=port
            )
```

To create a new database, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426448/creating-a-postgresql-db-using-psycopg2) explains it. Key line is:

```
con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
```

Comment: [This article](http://andyfiedler.com/2016/10/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-in-python) proposes an alternative way (I did not try it)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using the SQLALCHEMY library. 
First, you need to install the SQLALCHEMY library using pip, if you don't have pip on your computer install, you will know-how using a simple google search

> > pip install sqlalchemy

Here is the code snippet that do what you want:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
import os

# Put your URL in an environment variable and connect.
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

# Some variables you need.
var1 = 12
var2 = "Einstein"
# Execute statements
db.execute("SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id=:id, username=:username"\
           ,{"id": var1, "username": var2}).fetchall()

# Don't forget to commit if you did an insertion,etc...
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to parse the DATABASE_URL provided by Heroku with the urllib.parse as suggested above, but the following worked for me:

The URL I retrieved from Heroku was in the format:

postgres://username:password@host:port/database

for example:

postgres://jticiuimwernbk:ff78903549d4c6ec13a53a8ffefcd201b937d54c35d976
@ec2-52-123-182-987.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbsd4fdf6c1awq

So I manually dissected it as follows:

```
user = 'jticiuimwernbk'
password = 'ff78903549d4c6ec13a53a8ffefcd201b937d54c35d976'
host = 'ec2-52-123-182-987.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
port = '5432'
database = 'dbsd4fdf6c1awq'
    
#Then created the connection using the above:
    
con = psycopg2.connect(database=database,
user=user,
password=password,
host=host,
port=port)

# and now I was able to perform queries:

cur = conn.cursor()
results = cur.execute("<some SQL query>;").fetchall()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```