# This error message {"error":{"id":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid credentials provided."}} when I click on Heroku Postgres

Tags: python, heroku

I am new to python and am trying to set up Flask and Python.  I need to set my DATABASE_URL to run flask, but I can't find out my database url, because when I click on Heroku Postgres in my dashboard over view I get the error message:

{"error":{"id":"unauthorized","message":"Invalid credentials provided."}}

Any ideas?  Feel like I'm trapped in a weird circle.

Thanks in advance
Vicky

Answer (score 0):

I would try following the breadcrumbs from the chain of answers here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41812323/6529424

you need to configure your app and settings correctly.

Comment: If this fixed your problem please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, seemed to have sorted it, not quite sure how.  Heroku was showing details I required today, so maybe it was something to do with their site yesterday.